# echoing table from array number of doubled

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

Depending on which option a user chooses, there can be a different number Because of this, I created a function that will generate a table from two arrays. The first one has the name of the column headers and the second one, the actual data. This is my function:

```
function terminalTables ($numCol, $tableName, $data, $colName, $aircraft, $servicePack){

echo '<h3> Tail: '.$aircraft.'<br> Service pack: '.$servicePack.'</h3>';
echo '<table id="'.$tableName.'"  cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2"  style="text-align:center;" class="db-table db-table dTableWidth dataTable no-footer">';
echo '<thead>';
foreach ($colName as $col){
    echo '<th scope="col" style="white-space:nowrap">column:'.$col.'<th>';
}
/*for ($ii = 0; $colName[$ii] != NULL; $ii++){
    echo "<script>alert(\"column name: $colName[$ii]\");</script>";
    echo '<th scope="col" style="white-space:nowrap">'.$colName[$ii].'<th>';
}*/
echo '</thead>';
echo '<tbody>';
for ($iii = 0; $data[$iii] != NULL; $iii++){
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($j = 0; $j < $numCol; $j++){
        echo "<td style='white-space:nowrap; padding-left:1em; padding-right:1em;'>".$data[$iii][$j].'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
exit; }
```

All the data is being displayed correctly but the number of columns is duplicated in thead

When we inspect element on table head, this is what we get:

```html
<table id="datatable" class="db-table db-table dTableWidth dataTable no-footer" style="text-align:center;" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" style="white-space:nowrap">column:Event Time</th>
      <th></th>
      <th scope="col" style="white-space:nowrap">column:Event Type</th>
      <th></th>
      <th scope="col" style="white-space:nowrap">column:Rx Bytes Since power on (KB)</th>
      <th></th>
      <th scope="col" style="white-space:nowrap">column:Tx Bytes Since power on (KB)</th>
      <th></th>
      <th scope="col" style="white-space:nowrap">column:Link Start Time</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

Notice that in front of each actual column, we have column:NAME. We have in total five actual columns and 5 . Because of this my table is completely pushed to one side.

[image: picture of the table with yellow highlight on colulmn: and the empty columns]

I've been trying to debug this for too long and now my head hurts. What did I do wrong? Thank you very much.

Comment: `<th>` tags need to wrapped in `<tr>`s just like `<td>`s do

Comment: `$data[$iii] != NULL;` should probably be `$iii < count($data);`

Comment: It's true I forgot the <tr></tr> but I stillhave the extra columns

Comment: For $data[$iii] != NULL; I can't do this since I don't know the number of rows that will be querried. That's why I do $data[$iii] != NULL; Besides, The problem isn't event in this part it's in the foreach part. That's where I'm getting the extra columns

Comment: That's why you should use `$iii < count($data);`, you don't have to know how many rows.

Comment: Ok I understand. Just read up on the count function in php. I'm still a noob in programming (started 4 months ago).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my mistake and I'm pissed at myself. This was the code that I originally had:

```
echo '<th scope="col" id="terminalTables">'.$col.'<th>';
```

Notice that at the end of the line I don't have a  but . Yep, I'm an idiot.
it should've been like this:

```
echo '<th scope="col" id="terminalTables">'.$col.'</th>';
```